# How to programmatically generate kubernetes config from GCP service account using python API

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-python-api

I already found the way using `gcloud` CLI.

```
gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file=serviceaccount.json
gcloud container clusters get-credentials $clusterName \
    --zone=$zone --project=$project
kubectl config view --minify --flatten
```

However, to eliminate dependency to gcloud cli, Is there any programmatic way to achieve a similar result as above? Preferably using API exposed in Google's python client library.

My expected result is a portable config file that can be passed to any `kubectl --kubeconfig=...` command.

---

**update**: I have found that the commands I showed above results in a kube config file that still depends on gcloud cli as auth helper, probably to automatically handle token expiration. So, any workarounds are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a shell script which basically does exactly what you are expecting.

https://gitlab.com/workshop21/open-source/rbac